# Permissions issue on cifs mount between Ubuntu and Mavericks

Tags: linux, macos, permissions, share, mount

On my Linux box running Ubuntu 12.04LTS I am able to mount a share using `cifs`.

The shared folder in question is located at a Mac Pro running Mavericks.

Here is the `fstab` on the Ubuntu/Linux box.

```
//132.13.6.5/Data /home/sro/Mount cifs username=sro,password=psw,nounix,sec=ntlmssp,rw
```

**/Mount** on the Linux box has these permissions:

```
drwxr-xr-x 21 root    root          0 Jan 16 13:29 Mount
```

I can read **/Mount/Data** but not write (I get a permission error).

I think this is because **/Mount** is created by `root` and I am trying this a user.

But I am unable to change **/Mount** permissions or ownership even using `sudo`.

On the Mac/Mavericks side, **/Data** has read/write permissions.

Any ideas how to solve this?

Comment: What is the relationship between /Mount and /home/sro/Mount?

Comment: `sro` is the user in Ubuntu. So `/Mount` is the share mounted in this user's home folder as `/home/sro/Mount`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue here was a missing `UID/GID` pair. Apparently when those are absent the default owner of the share will be root.

So my fstab line should look like this:

```
//132.13.6.5/Data /home/sro/Mount cifs username=sro,password=psw,nounix,sec=ntlmssp,rw,uid=1001,gid=1001
```

Two things:

- your UID/GID may not be `1001` so better check with the `id` command first
- you may want to use permission masks as detailed [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/113733/how-do-i-correctly-mount-a-ntfs-partition-in-etc-fstab).

Answer (score 1):

add to your fstab line `uid=your_user_name` your line will be:

```
//132.13.6.5/Data /home/sro/Mount cifs username=sro,password=psw,nounix,sec=ntlmssp,rw,uid=your_user_name
```

That way you are asking linux to set that user as owner of filesystem being mounted.